# How to open a file externally using built-in commands?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

`command:revealFileInOS` is opening the folder where the file is, instead of opening the file.

Am I using the wrong command?

I also tried the command `vscode.open` but it opens the file inside of `vscode`.

I'm not trying to open the file in `vscode`, i'm trying to open it like if you were just double clicking/opening it.

```js
const uri = vscode.Uri.file(item.originalImagePath);
const args = [uri];
const openFileCommandUrl = vscode.Uri.parse(
    `command:revealInExplorer?${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(args))}`);

const browseFileCommandUrl = vscode.Uri.parse(
    `command:revealFileInOS?${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(args))}`);
```

Comment: When you debug your extension, it opens in a separate `ExtensionHost` Window, but the `console.log()s` will appear in the Debug Console where you started - where you started the debug session from.

Comment: where are you using this `result`, have you looked at command `vscode.open`

Comment: @rioV8 vscode.open " Opens the provided resource in the editor." im trying just to open the file as if you were double clicking on it. Its a picture. I have edited the question to clarify it.

Comment: `like if you were just double clicking/opening it.` Where do you double click it?

Comment: @rioV8 it was an example, how do you open a file in windows? double clicking it or right click > open, i was referring that im trying to open a file like this, on windows and not inside of vscode.

Comment: that means VSC must have knowledge of all the desktops available in Windows/Linux/MacOS, it is controlled by the file associations of the desktop

Comment: i have no idea what you are saying, if it can open a folder why it can open a file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built-in way to open a file in the OS's default application for that file within vscode.  See [Add ability to open files with the OS's default application](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/92689): on the Backlog.

But this package looks promising: [open](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open), that is a npm link.

1. `npm install open` in your extension folder.  Make sure you can see it in your `package.json` `devDependencies` after you do this.
2. `const open = require("open");` or whatever you want to name it in the file(s) you want to use it in.
3. `await open(<yourFullPathFileNameHere>)`  so your `item.originalImagePath` should work there.

Here is how I tested it to have the current editor - containing an image - open that image in the default application:

```js
const filePath = vscode.window.tabGroups.activeTabGroup.activeTab.input.uri.fsPath;
await open(filePath);       // using whatever you named it in the require
```

It works well for me on W11.  There are a few options to use with the `open` command.

Comment: i tried it like this: https://pastebin.com/ridw78vG, however as soon i hover the file it get opened, how i set it to be opened only when user click in the button "open"?

Comment: this is the file/line i'm working: [decorator.ts](https://github.com/kisstkondoros/gutter-preview/blob/fa124f5758d8e48ba4434e736167b3bc3429862b/src/decorator.ts#L139) when i hover the picture it creates this widget: https://i.imgur.com/pGrZbq2.png, `open` should be displaying 'blue' like `Open containing folder`, but its not working, my goal is to open the file only when user click the "Open".